# SQL Server Linked Server OLEDB hung threads - login issue

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server

We use linked server connection from SQL Server 2014 database to Oracle 11. Today, there were about 50+ threads hung in our SQL Server, waiting on OLEDB linked server connections for over 3 hours and our investigation from Oracle side determined that none of these queries are actively running in Oracle.

Answer (score 3):

**Issue**: Multiple hung threads in SQL Server
**Root-cause**: Expired Oracle password. SQL Server doesn't correctly report back login errors from linked servers and gets in to a hung mode.
**Resolution**: Reset Oracle password, updated linked server and restarted SQL Server DB.